# Speeding up Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: python, dijkstra

I have Dijkstra algyrithm:

```
   # ==========================================================================
# We will create a dictionary to represent the graph
# =============================================================================
graph = {
    'a' : {'b':3,'c':4, 'd':7},
    'b' : {'c':1,'f':5},
    'c' : {'f':6,'d':2},
    'd' : {'e':3, 'g':6},
    'e' : {'g':3, 'h':4},
    'f' : {'e':1, 'h':8},
    'g' : {'h':2},
    'h' : {'g':2}
}

def dijkstra(graph, start, goal):
    shortest_distance = {}     # dictionary to record the cost to reach to node. We will constantly update this dictionary as we move along the graph.
    track_predecessor = {}     # dictionary to keep track of path that led to that node.
    unseenNodes = graph.copy() # to iterate through all nodes
    infinity = 99999999999     # infinity can be considered a very large number
    track_path = []            # dictionary to record as we trace back our journey

    # Initially we want to assign 0 as the cost to reach to source node and infinity as cost to all other nodes
    for node in unseenNodes:
        shortest_distance[node] = infinity
    shortest_distance[start] = 0

    # The loop will keep running until we have entirely exhausted the graph, until we have seen all the nodes
    # To iterate through the graph, we need to determine the min_distance_node every time.
    while unseenNodes:
        min_distance_node = None
        for node in unseenNodes:
            if min_distance_node is None:
                min_distance_node = node
            elif shortest_distance[node] < shortest_distance[min_distance_node]:
                min_distance_node = node

        # From the minimum node, what are our possible paths
        path_options = graph[min_distance_node].items()

        # We have to calculate the cost each time for each path we take and only update it if it is lower than the existing cost
        for child_node, weight in path_options:
            if weight + shortest_distance[min_distance_node] < shortest_distance[child_node]:
                shortest_distance[child_node] = weight + shortest_distance[min_distance_node]
                track_predecessor[child_node] = min_distance_node

        # We want to pop out the nodes that we have just visited so that we dont iterate over them again.
        unseenNodes.pop(min_distance_node)

    # Once we have reached the destination node, we want trace back our path and calculate the total accumulated cost.
    currentNode = goal
    while currentNode != start:
        try:
            track_path.insert(0, currentNode)
            currentNode = track_predecessor[currentNode]
        except KeyError:
            print('Path not reachable')
            break
    track_path.insert(0, start)

    #  If the cost is infinity, the node had not been reached.
    if shortest_distance[goal] != infinity:
        print('Shortest distance is ' + str(shortest_distance[goal]))
        print('And the path is ' + str(track_path))
```

It works fine if I have a small amount of nodes (like in the code), but I have graph with around 480 000 nodes and by my approximate calculation it will find in such a big array path in 7.5 hours and that is only 1 way! How could I make it work faster? In OSM, for instance it calculates in seconds!

Comment: This question is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. You could also check out the networkx source for this algorithm [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/unweighted.html#bidirectional_shortest_path)

Comment: You should have a look at `numba`

Answer (score 1):

Usually these kind of things can be improved by using numba. I've done a quick example of how you could implement this. In pycharm it does output a lot of extra stuff, but that is not really all that important.

The way it works is that instead of reading everything line by line, numba compiles your code. For short programs this increases the run time by a couple seconds. However, you're talking about several hours, so this will definitely make your code faster.

```
# ==========================================================================
# We will create a dictionary to represent the graph
# =============================================================================
from numba import jit

graph = {
    'a' : {'b':3,'c':4, 'd':7},
    'b' : {'c':1,'f':5},
    'c' : {'f':6,'d':2},
    'd' : {'e':3, 'g':6},
    'e' : {'g':3, 'h':4},
    'f' : {'e':1, 'h':8},
    'g' : {'h':2},
    'h' : {'g':2}
}

@jit
def _dijkstra(graph, start, goal):
    shortest_distance = {}     # dictionary to record the cost to reach to node. We will constantly update this dictionary as we move along the graph.
    track_predecessor = {}     # dictionary to keep track of path that led to that node.
    unseenNodes = graph.copy() # to iterate through all nodes
    infinity = 99999999999     # infinity can be considered a very large number
    track_path = []            # dictionary to record as we trace back our journey

    # Initially we want to assign 0 as the cost to reach to source node and infinity as cost to all other nodes
    for node in unseenNodes:
        if node in shortest_distance:
            del shortest_distance[node]
        shortest_distance[node] = infinity
    del shortest_distance[start]
    shortest_distance[start] = 0

    # The loop will keep running until we have entirely exhausted the graph, until we have seen all the nodes
    # To iterate through the graph, we need to determine the min_distance_node every time.
    while unseenNodes:
        min_distance_node = None
        for node in unseenNodes:
            if min_distance_node is None:
                min_distance_node = node
            elif shortest_distance[node] < shortest_distance[min_distance_node]:
                min_distance_node = node

        # From the minimum node, what are our possible paths
        path_options = graph[min_distance_node].items()

        # We have to calculate the cost each time for each path we take and only update it if it is lower than the existing cost
        for child_node, weight in path_options:
            if weight + shortest_distance[min_distance_node] < shortest_distance[child_node]:
                if child_node in shortest_distance:
                    del shortest_distance[child_node]
                if child_node in track_predecessor:
                    del track_predecessor[child_node]
                shortest_distance[child_node] = weight + shortest_distance[min_distance_node]
                track_predecessor[child_node] = min_distance_node

        # We want to pop out the nodes that we have just visited so that we dont iterate over them again.
        unseenNodes.pop(min_distance_node)

    return track_path, track_predecessor, shortest_distance, infinity

def dijkstra(graph, start, goal):
    track_path, track_predecessor, shortest_distance, infinity = _dijkstra(graph, start, goal)

    # Once we have reached the destination node, we want trace back our path and calculate the total accumulated cost.
    currentNode = goal
    while currentNode != start:
        try:
            track_path.insert(0, currentNode)
            currentNode = track_predecessor[currentNode]
        except KeyError:
            print('Path not reachable')
            break
    track_path.insert(0, start)

    #  If the cost is infinity, the node had not been reached.
    if shortest_distance[goal] != infinity:
        print('Shortest distance is ' + str(shortest_distance[goal]))
        print('And the path is ' + str(track_path))

dijkstra(graph, 'a', 'h')
```

The reason that I split it into `dijkstra` and `_dijkstra` is because I couldn't get numba to compile the second half.

Comment: gives me an error :  global name 'mark_try_block' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be your use of `unseenNodes`. On each iteration, you search for the `node` minimising `shortest_distance[node]` by iterating over all of the nodes in `unseenNodes`, which takes O(V) time. This is done from inside a loop which iterates V times, so the overall complexity is O(V² + E), where the E term is for the other loop over `path_options` which considers each edge at most a constant number of times.

It is more efficient to use a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) data structure such as a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) in order to perform the "find and remove minimum" operation in less than O(V) time. Note that you only need to insert a node into the priority queue once you have a path to it. Pseudocode for implementing Dijkstra's algorithm using a priority queue can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue).